How to prove there exists such a constant C that this integral inequality holds
Let $f(x)$ be continuous and positive on $[0, 1]$ function and $H \in (0, 1)$ is fixed. How to prove that there exists such a constant $C \in [0, 1-H]$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_{C}^{C+H}f(t)dt < \frac{H}{1-H} \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt
\end{align*}
I know how to prove this for $H \geq \frac{1}{2}$: in case $H \geq \frac{1}{2}$ we can trivially put $C=0$ and get
\begin{align*}
(1-H) \int_{0}^{H}f(t)dt < H \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt\\
\iff \int_{0}^{H}f(t)dt < 2H \int_{0}^{H}f(t)dt +H \int_{H}^{1}f(t)dt
\end{align*}
and because $f>0$ we have $2H \int_{0}^{H}f(t)dt +H \int_{H}^{1}f(t)dt > 2H \int_{0}^{H}f(t)dt \geq  \int_{0}^{H}f(t)dt$ ( because $2H \geq 1$) and the claim follows.
But I don't know what should I do in case $H< \frac{1}{2}$. I tried to consider $C$ such that $\int_{C}^{C+H}f(t)dt = \min_{y \in [0, 1-H]}\int_{y}^{y+H}f(t)dt$ but I couldn't finish my proof.

Assuming $H<1/2$. First note that $H>H-H^2$ so that $\frac{H}{1-H}>H$. Let's take $H=1/3$ for example. Now divide $[0,1]$ into thirds and consider the integral of $f$ over those divisions, call them $A,B,C$. Certainly they cannot all be greater than $H\int_0^1 f(t)$ as then $\int_0^1 f = A+B+C > 3 * H\int_0^1 f = \int_0^1 f$. So for one, say $A$ we have $A\le H\int_0^1 f < \frac{H}{1-H}\int_0^1 f$. And you can take $C=0$. That's the idea... can you generalize?

@beeclu I think I got very close, but still can't finish. We divide $[0;1]$ on $\lceil \frac{1}{H} \rceil$ parts and then for some $i$ must be $H\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt \geq \int_{A_{i}} f(t)dt$ ( if not, then $\int_{0}^{1}fdt=\int_{A_{1}}+...+\int_{A_{\lceil \frac{1}{H} \rceil}}> \lceil \frac{1}{H} \rceil H \int_{0}^{1}fdt \geq \int_{0}^{1}fdt$ ). Hence $\int_{A_{i}} f(t)dt \leq H \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt< \frac{H}{1-H} \int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$ and len$(A_{i}) \leq H$ we can choose $C$ such that $A_{i} \subseteq [C;C+H]$ and then $\int_{A_{i}}fdt \leq \int_{C}^{C+H}fdt$ but it is not enough (should be >)

Even if we did get $>$ this would not work in the general case since $H$ will not always be in the nice form of $1/n$. So you will need to figure that out first.

@beeclu no, this would work, because I considered $H$ any real from $(0;1)$ and that's why I divided on $\lceil \frac{1}{H} \rceil$ parts. I don't use $H=1/n$ anywhere

If $H=2/5$ then you need to divide into 3 parts, but then your third interval is $[2/3,1]$. In the case you need to choose this interval, $C$ is outside $[0,1-H]$.

@beeclu no, in this case $A_{3}=[2/3;1]$, let $C = 3/5=1-H$, then $[C;C+H]=[3/5;1]$ and $A_{3}=[2/3;1] \subseteq [C;C+H]=[3/5;1]$ and integral over $A_{3}=[2/3;1]$ will be less than integral over $[C;C+H]$. I don't know how to generalize

Sorry, I misread. I knew the proof would not work after you divided it into⌈1/⌉ and did not read carefully after that.

I chose to give an example with $H=1/n$ because then you can partition nicely into an even number of intervals with length $H$. This was just to illustrate the idea that "if integrals over intervals of length $H$ are all greater than $H\int_0^1 f$ there is a contradiction". That is the idea you should try to be generalizing, not the specific construction of partitioning $[0,1]$

Think about comparing the average value of $f$ on an interval vs. the average of $f$ taken over  its complement.

@MathFont I couldn't apply this for solving the problem. Can you help please?

@beeclu I couldn't generalize your idea unfortunately

Consider the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{H} \int_x^{x+H} f(t)\ dt$. 1. What is $g$? 2. What can we say about it?

@beeclu it is an average of $f(t)$ on $[x;x+H]$. It is continuously differentiable
